# KeyError: "There's no child of Graph by the name of: collection name"

Tags: pyarango

while creating a graph, I am seeing this error. How to define the child of a collection or graph?

Comment: I am using database.createGraph function

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, was trying to figure it out, all day long ):<

Turns out, here's how things work.

Let's assume we are connected and everything:

```
conn = Connection(arangoURL="http://arangodb:8529", username="root", password="secret")
db = conn.createDatabase(name="mydb3")
```

Turns out, Graphs are wayyy different from collections, and even though you can make collections of type Collection `db.createCollection(className="Collection", name="Users")` and collections of type Edges, `db.createCollection(className="Edges", name="Follows")` really easily, you can't make graphs like `db.createGraph(name="Social", createCollections=False)` right off the bat, the way you can with collections. According to the code that the pyArango developer wrote (and his reaaalllyy sparse hard to understand documentation) you have to first kind of *explain the structure of this specific graph* before you can make a new graph. And you're supposed to do this by making a bunch of classes that extend other classes that he wrote. He wrote this (vaguely, lol) in [his documentation](http://bioinfo.iric.ca/~daoudat/pyArango/database.html#pyArango.database.Database.createGraph) ):

The creator of pyArango wants the structure of the specific edges and vertices that we will be using in the graph, to be declared with fancy extra logging, before we make a graph. **There are actually two ways to create a collection.** In the docs, it says that

> ```
> createCollection(className='Collection', waitForSync=False, **colArgs)
> ```
>
> Creates a collection and returns it. ClassName the name of a class inheriting from Collection or Egdes, it can also be
>   set to ‘Collection’ or ‘Edges’ in order to create untyped collections
>   of documents or edges.

**What he means is that he actually intends for you to usually make collections not like this:** `db.createCollection(className="Edges", name="Follows")` **but by creating a new class first, a class that extends either Collection or Edges**, and to have fancy extra definitions, in that class. Basically, when you create it in the special way I'm about to show you, it keeps a log of these special, non-default collections, in a metaclass. In order for the graph to work, you can't use the little default shortcut, you have to actually make the classes because the graph thing will check for their existence inside the metaclass. After we make the new classes that extend Edges and Collection, we can leave them empty for now. Usually, if a developer wants to document *in the class definition not the database* a few fields or some other things that these collections have, he'll put them in these class extensions.

```
class Follows(Edges) :
    pass

class Users(Collection) :
    pass
```

**Create your actual collections, only after you make these classes!** You might be tempted to do `db.createCollection(className="Collection", name="Users")` before you make these classes, but don't. It will make pyArango confused. Also, instead of writing it the default way, like `db.createCollection(className="Collection", name="Users")` now, we will create a vew vertices for testing, like this:

```
db.createCollection(className="Users")
doc = db["Users"].createDocument()
doc._key = "custom_key"
doc["name"] = "Tesla"
doc["age"] = "28"
doc.save()
doc = db["Users"].createDocument()
doc._key = "custom_key2"
doc["name"] = "Porsche"
doc.save()
```

and a few edges for testing:

```
db.createCollection(className="Follows")
doc = db["Follows"].createEdge()
doc._key = "custom_key"
doc["_from"] = "Users/custom_key"
doc["_to"] = "Users/custom_key2"
doc.save()
```

And now is the part where you describe the structure of your graph, done by extending the graph class, in this specific way. Once again, no clue what _orphanedCollections is but I'll let you know if I find out. The `'Follows'` in the following code block has to be the same word as the `Follows` in `class Follows(Edges) :` and the same word as `db.createCollection(className="Edges", name="Follows")`, basically, you probably named your edge collection something other than Follows. **Make sure it is the same name, in those three locations. And the same goes for all the Users** - inside of `class Social(Graph)` and in the place where you write class `Users(Collection)` and any time you do something like `db["Users"].createDocument()` - all these places use the same name. So if you decide to have a collection with a different name, maybe People or something, make sure you are consistent throughout your code with it. Those 3 spots correspond to the same name. Not sure how.

```
class Social(Graph):
    _edgeDefinitions = (EdgeDefinition ('Follows', fromCollections = ["Users"], toCollections = ["Users"]), )
    _orphanedCollections = []
```

and now, finally, after all that trouble, you will be able to write the following line:

```
g = db.createGraph(name="Social", createCollections=False)
```

Make sure you use the same name where you write name="**Social**" and where you wrote previously class **Social**(Graph) the names correspond because createGraph literally calls that class you wrote. When you're writing name="Social" you're passing that entire class as a parameter to createGraph. Eek.

Anyways, *after all that trouble, it should work now*. If you open up the arangodb web interface, log in, select mydb3, and click "graph" you'll see the graph you made. yay.

Note: For some reason, if you add new edges and vertices after creating the graph, (like below) all the ones you had before creating the graph ... disappear. If I figure out why, I'll edit the answer. But for now, just create them only before or only after.

```
a = g.createVertex('Users', {"name": 'Toyota',  "_key": 'custom_key6'});
b = g.createVertex('Users',  {"name": 'Honda',    "_key": 'custom_key7'});
g.link('Follows', a, b, {"extra_info": 'testing1', "_key": 'custom_key8'})
```